# Django operational error in postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

im having an issue with django, im trying to create a data base on django for my application i have set my conection like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'Proyecto_OSC',
        'USER': 'posgresql',
        'PASSWORD': 'aa121292',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

then i tried to create my models like this:

```
class TipoOrganizacion(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tipos de Organizacion"


class Actividades(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Actividades"


class AreasInteres(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Areas de interes"
        verbose_name = "Area de interes"

class TiposRedesSociales(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tipo

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tipos de redes sociales"
        verbose_name = "tipo de red social"

class RedSocial(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tipo = models.ManyToManyField(TiposRedesSociales)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Redes sociales"
        verbose_name = "Red social"

class Organizacion(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    poblacion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    dias = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    iniciohora = models.TimeField()
    finhora = models.TimeField()
    nombrecontacto = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    numeropersonas = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    recursos = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(TipoOrganizacion)
    actividades = models.ManyToManyField(Actividades)
    areas = models.ManyToManyField(AreasInteres)
    red = models.ForeignKey(RedSocial)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "organizaciones"
        verbose_name = "organizacion"
```

i already tried to manage.py validate to verify errors with the syntax on my models and its says 0 errors, then after doing syncdb it happens this:

```
C:\Users\Abdul Hamid\PycharmProjects\Proyecto_OSC>python manage.py syncdb 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\base.py", line 114, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 160, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 132, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 549, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\base.py", line 114, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

so i already tried creating the database inside postgres using pgadminIII without creating the tables
and it keeps hapening this error, im wondering if i have to create the entire database with all the tables or does django creates the whole database with just writing the models?
am i doing something wrong? i belive i am but im not sure

im not a profesional thought 
im still learning

im sorry for my english, it is not my first language

btw thanks in advance

Comment: did you "pip install psycopg2" ?

Comment: yes of course, sorry for not pointing that in the description

Comment: Double check the username and password for typos? I noticed the user is 'posgresql' a lot of times the user is 'postgresql' maybe you are missing the 't'?

Comment: ok i changed it to postgresql asumming that my user its the one i use in postgresql but it is droping me the same operational error exception, i gotta point out that im trying to create the tables on postgresql using django

Comment: ok i realized that the username was postgres not postgresql and that postgres server wasnt listening localhost

Comment: thank you all for your time